# Asynchronous MVVM for WPF C# using MongoDB

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, xaml, mvvm

So my situation is this: I want to be able to use MVVM with my WPF application using MongoDB. I am very new to MVVM (I know very little of it), but I've got some experience using .NET and WPF.

I have a namespace for recalling MongoDB collections, with the Model component stored there as a class called "User"

Model (in a separate namespace):

```
public class User
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // other methods listed here

    public async static Task<List<User>> getUserList()
    {
        // allows me to get a list of users
        var col = MongoDBServer<User>.openMongoDB("Users");
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Exists("name");

        List<User> userList = await col.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

        return userList;
    }
}
```

I've created a very basic ViewModelBase (abstract ViewModelBase):

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(handler == null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And a derived class for handling the User Lists (ViewModel):

```
public class UserListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private User _user;
    private ObservableCollection<User> _userList;

    public User user
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("user");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> userList
    {
        get { return _userList; }
        set
        {
            _userList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("userList");
        }
    }

    public UserListViewModel()
    {
        user = new User();
        this.userList = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        // since MongoDB operations are asyncrhonous, the async method "getUserList()" is used to fill the observable collection
        getUserList().Wait();
    }

    public async Task getUserList()
    {
        var UserListRaw = await User.getUserList();
        this.userList = new ObservableCollection<User>(UserListRaw);
    }
}
```

The view component is as a simple window with a listbox, as follows (View):

```
<Window x:Class="UserManagementMVVM.UsersWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserManagementMVVM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="UsersWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:UserListViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <!-- Receiving error for this XAML block saying "Object reference not set to instance of an object -->
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}">
        <ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding userList}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The App.Xaml and its codebehind are left untouched, as is the View's codebehind.

When I run the program, nothing shows up (ie: The Window starts, but the ListBox is empty even though there is data). I will soon add some button functionality that will perform atomic operations with MongoDB.

I've been trying for nearly 2 weeks to make my own MVVM program for this, with no success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your userList contain data?

Comment: Yes. It is a list of "Users" that I call on from MongoDB that has data. It is filled with the "getUserList()" function in the ViewModel.

Comment: Did you try ... debugging?  "Nothing shows up" isn't really enough information to go by.

Comment: yeah, I mean did you see it filled in the debugger?

Comment: Will -- where should I start debugging from? By "nothing shows up" i mean that the ListBox is empty when the program starts. Apologies for not elaborating.

Comment: gilmishal - I tried my own OnStartup method in App.xaml (I know, I lied about App.Xaml being untouched, although I removed the code after I realized it didn't work). When I got past the getUserList() function, the "count" in the variable tracker showed 4 (which is how many users there are stored in the MongoDB database.) Does this make any sense?

Comment: Don't use Active Record pattern with MVVM, as it will break one major advantage of MVVM: loose coupling. Consider using Repository pattern with Dependency Injection

Answer (score 1):

You are not putting the getUserList() return value into a variable

I assume you mean to do the following

```
Task.Run(async ()=>this.userList = await getUserList());
```

this shall work you should think wether you want to wait for the task to finish or not, and than place a `.Wait()` after it.

Your other issue might be the way you bind to the ViewModel in the context it should use StaticResource instead of binding

like This:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
```

Comment: This would require that I make the getUserList() and awaitable function, and I can't put that into a constructor (they aren't asynchronous or awaitable).

If you check the getUserList() function you'll see it's designed to perform an asynchronous task while running the constructor function, and it updates the userList property intrisically.

Comment: you could put it inside a task and run it from inside the constructor, but there should be a better way. Anyway the problem you have is most probably the fact that you are not populating the userList

Comment: Thanks... the code worked, but the ListBox is still unpopulated. I tried debugging at both the getUserList and the constructor function, but it doesn't appear to even reach it.

Comment: The debugger got to the constructor, but I'm getting a Target Invocation exception at "this.UserLIst = new ObservableCollection<User>();" ... any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: You should look at the stacktrace and/or inner exceptions to find out why you get that, because I can't see any reason right now

Comment: Ok... I don't really know how to do that... But thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window x:Class="UserManagementMVVM.UsersWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserManagementMVVM"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="UsersWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.DataContext>
    <!--You have to set the DataContext -->
    <local:UserListViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding userList}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

You have to set the DataContext right. i changed your xaml. but i prefer setting the DataContext for the Mainwindow in Codebehind or app.xaml.cs.

eg: app.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
 {
      var data = new MainWindowViewmodel();
      this.MainWindow = new MainWindow(data);
      this.MainWindow.Show();
 }
```

all other DataContext for my views are done with DataTemplates within the ResourceDictionary

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyOtherViewmodel}">
    <local::MyOtherViewmodelView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to give credit to both **gilMishal** and **blindmeis** for pointing me in the right direction. Both of your answers have helped. Here is my updated (and functional!) code:

App.xaml.cs has been modified as follows (Credit to **blindmeis**):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        UsersWindow window = new UsersWindow();
        var ViewModel = new UserListViewModel();
        window.DataContext = ViewModel;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel has been updated:

```
public class UserListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private User _user;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _userList; // changed from "User" class to string

    public User user
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("user");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> userList
    {
        get { return _userList; }
        set
        {
            _userList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("userList");
        }
    }

    public UserListViewModel()
    {
        userList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Task.Run(async () => this.userList = await getUserList()); // Credit to gilMishal
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> getUserList()
    {
        var UserListRaw = await User.getUserList();
        var userListOC = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        foreach (var doc in UserListRaw) // extracting the "name" property from each "User" object
        {
            userListOC.Add(doc.name);
        }

        return userListOC;
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<Window x:Class="UserManagementMVVM.UsersWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserManagementMVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="UsersWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:UserListViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid> <!-- data context removed from here, credit blindmeis -->
        <ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding userList}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Don't call long running and async Tasks inside a constructor. Consider using a NavigationService and the prism-inspired `INavigationAware` interface. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457037/background-loading-in-mvvm-and-constructor-injection/28457714#28457714

Comment: Check the link to the other answer. It has direct links to the related classes in Prism (Prism is an opensource MVVM Framework developed by Microsoft). I'd suggest to work into Prism. It's pretty powerful once you get the grip of it and you don't have any restrictions to a specific other MVVM framework